# Compare table columns with current date in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write an excel VBA to compare columns of a table with the current date and highlight if true.

Here is an example table:

[image]

The code that I'm working on is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim tbl As Excel.ListObject 'Table name
    Dim lr As Excel.ListRow 'Row index
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet 'Work sheet
    'column names
    Dim keepInTouch As Range, invite As Range, present As Range, follow As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)                                 'select work book index 1
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("ContactList")                             'set ContactList to tbl
    Set keepInTouch = tbl.ListColumns("Keep in Touch").DataBodyRange    'Select the appropreate header
    Set invite = tbl.ListColumns("Invite").DataBodyRange
    Set present = tbl.ListColumns("Present").DataBodyRange
    Set follow = tbl.ListColumns("Follow").DataBodyRange
    'MsgBox tbl
    For Each lr In tbl.ListRows
        If lr.Range(1, tbl.ListColumns("Keep in Touch").Index).Value <> Date Then
            keepInTouch.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            keepInTouch.Font.ColorIndex = 1
            keepInTouch.Font.Bold = False
        'If keepInTouch(1).Value = Date And keepInTouch(1).Value <> "" Then
        ElseIf lr.Range(1, tbl.ListColumns("Keep in Touch").Index).Value = Date Then
            keepInTouch.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            keepInTouch.Font.ColorIndex = 2
            keepInTouch.Font.Bold = True
        End If
        Next lr
End Sub
```

Line 19: `If keepInTouch.Index = Date And keepInTouch.Index <> "" Then` causes

```
Run time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Should be easier with [conditional formatting](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/17/excel-conditional-formatting-dates/#based-current-date) and Range does not have `.Index` .. maybe you mean `.Value`

Comment: @Slai I have tried `.Value` but it gave `Run time error '13': Type mismatch`

Comment: Use `If keepInTouch(1).Value = Date Then` There is no need to check for a zero-length string since you are already checking to see if it is the current date.

Comment: That is acting like it's indexing an array value. After testing, If the first date of the column is today's date it will highlight the whole column and if the first date in the column is not today's date it will escape the whole `If statement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    If lr.Range(1, tbl.ListColumns("Keep in Touch").Index).Value = Date Then
```

For example `lr.Range(1, 2)` is the second column cell in the ListRow Range

```
keepInTouchIndex = tbl.ListColumns("Keep in Touch").Index
NameIndex = tbl.ListColumns("Name").Index

For Each lr In tbl.ListRows
    With lr.Range.Cells(1, NameIndex)
        If lr.Range.Cells(1, keepInTouchIndex).Value <> Date Then
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            .Font.ColorIndex = 2
            .Font.Bold = True
        Else
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            .Font.ColorIndex = 1
            .Font.Bold = False
        End If
    End With
Next lr
```

Comment: @Amir I changed it a bit after

Comment: I've adopted the changes. After each loop the formatting of each cell will be rested to default. 
* main code is updated with the changes

Comment: @Amir check the example.

Comment: That did it for this problem